# How to prepare for a race?

Tags: running, nutrition, racing

8 weeks ago, I asked this question: [how to run sub-45 10k](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/how-to-run-sub-45-10k).

Well, I've been training a lot and my race is on Sunday (in 2 days' time.)

- What / when should I eat in preparation?
- Do I need to carb-load for a 10k?
- Should I run / crosstrain / lift the day prior to the race?

Comment: Excellent question and nice to see you follow up :-)

Comment: Finished in 44:51 according to my watch `:D`

Comment: Well it seems you made the sub-45 bit ;-) Guess you run a tad faster than I do too!

Comment: my answer is thats great and well hell! keep up the good work and by the way my name is aisha and im a junior and i attend hillcrest ....

Comment: Similar question for a 5K: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/what-to-do-before-a-5k-race-day-advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 schools of thoughts on running the day before.
1) rest and save your glycogen stores for race day.

2) warm up and then run a few minutes at race pace. This could look like 10 minutes easy followed by 10 minutes of 30 seconds at 10k pace and 90 seconds jog.

If you tapered the week before, I prefer 2. If you haven't cut back mileage, choose 1. Really don't think you can go wrong with either though.

Eat before? Again, personal preference but choose something easily digestible and that you normally eat. Choose high carb, low protein, low fat. My personal favorite is a whole wheat bagel with a little bit of peanut butter about 2 hours before race time. Less time? Choose a spoon of honey.

If the race is Sunday, too late to truly carbo load. You need a few days before. BUT a pasta dinner the night before would be beneficial provided it isnt loaded with cheese. Besides a carbo load probably isn't needed for a 10k.

Oh and lifting, cross training, core, etc. - definitely skip if this is a goal race. Good luck and let us know what your new PR is!

Comment: Thanks Chris. I had tapered for the week before so I did as you said and ran a short time at race pace. I skipped breakfast but had a big dinner the night before. Broke my PB and achieved my target!

Comment: @rmx Great to hear!  Congrats on the PR.

Answer (score -1):

Keep to your training routine, about two days before the race, engage on weight lifting to build your muscles. On the event day, spend your time with your favourite friends and listening to your favourite music. Go with your greatest motivators to the race to keep your moods. Run with confidence and you will make it.

Comment: -1. Tapering is all about resting and recovering, not engaging in weightlifting sessions. Two days out from any event I wouldn't recommend any workout longer than 15-20 minutes of light work.